# Export all GA4 project Data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-4

Since last Wednesday we export our GA4 data to BigQuery with a once-a-day export. This works seamlessly, however at this moment we only have data starting from last Wednesday, the moment we created the data.
The project (website) launched earlier this year in September. Is there any possibility to export the data from before we created the BigQuery-export in GA4?

The data does exist in the analytics.google.com reports but we are unable to retrieve it in BigQuery.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be the possibility to backfill previous data using the Supermetrics Analytics connector from the GCP Marketplace. I am not aware of any other way.